# Velocity.js animation delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I am a little bit frustrated because velocity js acts strangely in my code.

How can these animations go in sequence if I haven't specified any delay time? After reading Velocity Docs I thought this should be simulations animations... But this is fired like: body animation, menu animation. It's even not the sequence in the code. Can someone point me the cause?

```
$('#pr-nav-icon').click(function() {
    $('#hamburger-menu-drop').velocity({marginLeft: "0px"}, {
        duration: 300,
        delay: 0,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
    });
    $('body').velocity({marginLeft: "440px"}, {
        duration: 300,
        delay: 0,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
    });
});
```

Here is my sass for this elements, if it could be the cause:

```
#hamburger-menu-drop {
  max-width: 420px;
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: $darktext;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: inset -10px 0 5px -5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.25);
  margin-left: -420px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.55;
  font-family: $titlefont;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  color: $darktext;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-smooth: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what was the problem and it was really a stupid mistake of mine. Of course, velocity.js was working normally, as pointed by Thomas. The problem was that I've tried to animate the menu that was in the body and the body itself, so the animations elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You duration is at "300" for animating the 'body' and the 'hamburger-menu-drop', you'll notice that if you set the duration on the body to 5 seconds and the 'hamburger-menu-drop' to .3 seconds you'll see one happen before the other. I've made the background of the body change to yellow so you will be able to visually see the changes happen.

```js
$('#pr-nav-icon').click(function() {
  $('#hamburger-menu-drop').velocity({
    marginLeft: "0px"
  }, {
    duration: 300,
    delay: 0,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
  });
  
    $('body').velocity({
    backgroundColor: "#ffcc3a"
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    delay: 0,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 15%;
}
#hamburger-menu-drop {
  max-width: 420px;
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: $darktext;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: inset -10px 0 5px -5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.25);
  margin-left: -420px;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.55;
  font-family: $titlefont;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  color: $darktext;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-smooth: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.4.2/velocity.min.js"></script>

<button id="pr-nav-icon">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="hamburger-menu-drop">HAMBURGER</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thomas. Thank you for your answer! The trick is I can't animate this two divs simultaneously. I thought if I put the same time and easing on two divs than they should animate together in a smooth motion to the right. But I get one translated and then another.